# confirm password in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm implementing a sign up page with the usual: username, password, confirm password, other info, and reCAPTCHA.

How do I go on about with the confirmation of passwords? This is my attempt but when I try to sign up with the passwords mismatched, I can still sign up...

User.groovy:

```
String password
transient confirmPassword

static constraints = {
    //removed other constraints
    password blank: false, nullable: false, validator: {password, obj ->
        def confirmPassword = obj.properties['confirmPassword']
        if(confirmPassword == null) return true 
        confirmPassword == password ? true : ['mismatch.passwords'] //"Passwords do not match"
    }
   //confirmPassword blank: false, nullable: false, bindable: true
}
```

UserController.groovy:

```
def save() {
    def userInstance = new User(params)


    def recaptchaOK = true
    if (!recaptchaService.verifyAnswer(session, request.getRemoteAddr(), params)) {
        recaptchaOK = false
    }
    if(!userInstance.hasErrors() && recaptchaOK && userInstance.save()) {
        recaptchaService.cleanUp(session)
        if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
            return
        }
        flash.message = message(code: 'create.user.successful')
        redirect(controller: 'login', action: "auth", id: userInstance.id)
        sendSignUp(userInstance.email,userInstance.firstName, userInstance.lastName)

        UserRole.create(userInstance, Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER"),true)
    }
    else {
        flash.recaptchafailed = message(code: 'recaptcha.failed')
        render(view: "create", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
    }
}
```

create.gsp (Just the fields for the password and confirm password):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 form-item fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: userInstance, field: 'password', 'error')}">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="password">
            <g:message code="user.password.label" default="Password" />
            <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <g:textField name="password" required="" class="form-control input-sm form-ship" value="${userInstance?.password}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

*

Comment: Grails convention warning:  Typically you don't want to see business logic in the controller, you'll want to refactor that into a service class.  The controller should just be used to route requests based on how the services process business logic.  Same goes for the persistence calls... those should be handled in their own service class.

Answer (score 2):

```
    String password;
    String confirmPassword;
    static constraints = {
        password nullable: false, blank: false
        confirmPassword nullable: false, blank: false, validator: { val, object ->
            if ((val != object.password)) {
                return 'passwordMismatch'
            }
            return true
```

try this for password missmatch

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. The problem is that your field confirmPassword is transient. I don't know if it is still true, but validator doesn't work with transient value.

In my case, I solved the problem using a validation in service:

```
def passwordValidation(String password, String passwordConfirmation) {

    String pattern = "((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,})";
    if (password.equals(passwordConfirmation) && password.matches(pattern)) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: So, do I remove the constraints and then put this in my BootstrapService.groovy? Then do I put an if statement in my UserController.groovy where if passwordValidation returns true, I'll proceed to checking the reCAPTCHA?

Comment: This is exactly what I did (without the Captcha). I created a service called "security" with my function. In my GSP, I have two fields "password" and "passwordConfirmation". In UserController, I have an IF Statement where if passwordValidation returns true, then the account can be created, else the user is redirect to the sign up page.